# Is asking about ComputerShare's services ontopic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I recently started getting into DRIP investing with SPP, and got my first share in the mail. I signed up on Computer Share, the comany who holds the stock for me, and tried registering for the DRIP/SPP. I have an issue about why I'm not certified, and would like to know if **asking about getting certified on an investing website is on topic or not**?

Answer (score 2):

The original question https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/33926/getting-certified-through-computer-share-for-my-drip-spp was a customer service issue, and you advised that it was resolved, with an ok to close the question.

In my opinion, such issues, e.g. those that can be answered by "go to X link on company home page, then Y link to request form," are not on-topic. Still, I only closed it after you advised you were all set.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why not. You're trying to get certified as an individual investor, aren't you?